# Eloquent JavaScript Chess Board Solution?

Tags: javascript

I am sorry for being noob but I think I am in the right place. I have been trying to solve chess board of eloquent javascript but it is so hard for me, even the solution provided:

```
var size = 8;
var board = "";
for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {  /* why 2 loops? */
 for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) { 
  if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) /* why is this? */    
  board += " ";   
else     
  board += "#"; 
  }  
 board += "\n";
}
console.log(board);
```

Can someone please explain lines further, I don't want to pass this problem without fully understanding.Also, Is this book also a good start for javascript?

Comment: 2 loops for 2 dimensions. `%` is the remainder/modulo operator. it returns a rest of an integer division.

Comment: if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) /* why is this? */...% is the mod operator, it is testing to see if the result is an even number. The two loops are because you have a board that is two dimensional

Comment: I am wondering why the # is not displaying on even number at different lines?

Comment: which book do you mean?

Comment: eloquentjavascript.net

Comment: I dont get this part so well, "for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {  /* why 2 loops? */
 for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) { 
  if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) /* why is this? */"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two loops are required to construct the two dimensions of the board. Have a look at:

[Chess Board](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/SCD_algebraic_notation.svg/756px-SCD_algebraic_notation.svg.png)

You can think of the outer loop as the rows (the numbers on the board) and the inner loop as the columns (the alphabet on the board). Each loop of the outer loops creates another row, and each loop of the inner loop creates another column in said row.

The `if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)` uses the `%` (modulo) to determine whether the `x + y` divided by `2` has a remainder. If the result is equal to `0` then it had no remainder, and thus is an even number so log out a space, otherwise log out a `#`, building your chess board pattern.

So for example the first square in the top left would be `(0 + 0) % 2` resulting in `0` so print a space, and the next square over would be `(1 + 0) % 2` would be `1` so print a `#`.

In regards to the book Eloquent JavaScript by Marijn Haverbeke, yes it's definitely a great book. It covers a lot of topics and is divided into isolated chapters so it's great as a reference as well. Though one downside I personally found with the book is that in certain chapters the author uses very complex and convoluted examples to demonstrate the usage of JavaScript.

Comment: I don't understand this so well,  but i am getting it,  "So for example the first square in the top left would be (0 + 0) % 2 resulting in 0 so print a space, and the next square over would be (0 + 1) % 2 would be 1 so print a #" why is x 0? what about the 2nd line and so on? why does it start with #

Comment: Look at `for (var x = 0; x < size; x++)`, `var x = 0` is saying, hey lets start the loop at `0`, where `x` is your counter to keep track of how many times the loop has occurred. `x < size` is a check to see if the counter is less than the `size`, if it is then keep looping. `x++` is saying that, for every loop we do, add `1` to our counter `x`. The first time we loop through, `x` is `0`, the second time, `x` is `1`, then `2`, etc. Until `x` is no longer less than `size`, which is when the loop stops. Since `((x + y) % 2 == 0)` is inside the loop, it can use the variable `x`, same with `y`.

Comment: Might be worth checking out Chapter 2  [**For Loops**[(http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_oupMC+5FKN) of Eloquent JavaScript for a little refresher.

Comment: @kevinto, I have a question: why is the inner loop `for (var x = 0; x < size; x++)` still working for the next rows? Shouldn't it end after first row? I mean - making second row `x` is greater than `var size = 8` , right? Or for every next row this `x` is being equal to `0` ? How does it work?

Comment: @Thinker-Tinker because the outer loop – for every time it is ran the `var x = 0` gets executed and thus reinitlisiing the `x` to `0` in `for (var x = 0; x < size; x++)`.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution, if linecounter is even, first internal loop is running, if linecounter is odd, second internal loop is running:

```
var line = "", size = 8, char;
for (var linecounter = 0; linecounter < size; linecounter++){
  if (linecounter % 2 == 0)
    for (var charcounter = 0; charcounter < size; charcounter++){
      if (charcounter % 2 == 0)
        char = "_";
      else
        char = "#";
        line = line + char;
    }
    else
      for (var charcounter = 0; charcounter < size; charcounter++){
        if (charcounter % 2 == 0)
          char = "#";
        else
          char = "_";
      line = line + char;
      }
line = line + "\n";
}
console.log(line);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an answer that gets the job done.

```
function makeGrid(rows){
  var str = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      if((i+j)%2===0){
        str += '#';
      } else {
        str += ' ';
      }
    }
    str += '\n';
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: OP was not asking for getting a job done that was already done.

Answer (score -1):

## My solution

```js
const { log } = console;
function createBoard(size){
  let board = "";
  for(let line = 1; line <= size; line ++){
    for(let column = 1; column <= size; column ++){
      board += (line%2 && column === 1) ? ' # ' : (column === size ) ? "# \n" : '# '; 
    }
  }
  log(board);
}
createBoard(Number(prompt("Board Size?")));
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Could you add a quick description of what this code is doing (maybe some comments in the code?) to help others understand this the code?

Comment: The OP was not asking for a solution, as they already had one.